# Unwrapped mesh as real mesh in 3d scene

Tags: mesh, uv

I need to have the unwrapped mesh of an object as 3d object itself.

More precisely I need to take a mesh, unwrap it and solidify the unwrapped one.

At the moment, the only way I know to do this is to unwrap the mesh, save the unwrapped mesh as SVG (from the UV Mapping window), import the SVG in the scene and extrude it.

Does anyone know a fastest and more direct way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've added an answer in the linked page with the Wrap Tools addon

Comment: Thanks! I check it out immediately.